# How can I see all iphone app icons in Xcode?

Tags: xcode10

When I submit my app from xcode to Apple store, it complaint that missing 57x57 and 72x72 icons. However, in the xcassets, don't have the slot to add 57x57 and 72x72 icon. May refer to the attached screenshots.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `AppIcon-1` from **Assets.xcassets**

Set all AppIcons in varies sizes.

Then setup

> AppIcon in Target->General->App Icons and Launch Images

[image]

Then *Clean* and *Run* your project. And verify on *simulator*. Then `archive` it

Answer (score 0):

By drag and drop icon is not right way according to me. 
**Try below method**

1.Take one image of your app icon

2.goto makeappicon.com website.

3.now upload image there and wait it will ask for email id to send icon set zip file.

4.extract that zip file find ios folder>copy whole content and paste it to your project folders asset folder and blah .

**All icons are set now**